# Run webpack without sudo

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, sudo

So I have an React application and, when I want to create the bundle, using the webpack command, it gives me an access error :

```
emittingError: EACCES: permission denied
```

when I try to run with sudo it works just fine.

Is there any way to run the webpack command without sudo?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: change the permissions on the directory it's running in?

Answer (score 1):

Try running it via npm script. E.g.:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
}
```

Additionally make sure that your output folder/files was not created manually before.